# Not calling done function of deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import _ from 'underscore';
import $script from 'scriptjs';


  var _apiLoaded = $.Deferred();

  window.initApi = function () {
    _apiLoaded.resolve();
    delete window.initApi;
  };

class X {
init(){
 url = "blahblah"
  $script([url + '&callback=initApi'], function () {
        });

 _apiLoaded.done(function () {  <Execution is skipping this function>
          test.initialized = true;
       });
}

getPred(query, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
 // this.init();
  _apiLoaded.done(function () {  <Execution is skipping this function>
    blah blah...
      });
    };
    this.getPred(query);
  });
}}
```

I am doing this from model:
gc = new X();
gcd = gc.init();

gc.getPred(requestParams.predQ, _.bind(this.success, this), errorHandler);

---

Can you explain in the above code & why its not executing  _apiLoaded.done(function () { ...
mainly in getPred
after _apiLoaded.done(function () {
its going to line 
        _apiLoaded.resolve();
        delete window.initApi;
not calling back done function at all

Comment: Who is calling `window.initApi`? What does this has to do with backbone? BTW this is not a tutorial site. Please read about promises and es6 classes.

Comment: Just curious - if you are already using jQuery, why not use its `$.ajax` method for loading the JSONP?!

Comment: thats not working, its somehow works only with $script